# Keras generator for multiple inputs model: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape () where an element of shape (None, None) was expected

Tags: keras, input, generator

I am currently trying to fit a model **with several inputs and many rows** and thus I use a  generator to train the model. 
 I wrote a custom generator to feed to my model :

```
class My_Custom_Generator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence) :
  
    def __init__(self, batch_size, df) :
        self.df = df
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    def __len__(self) :
        return (np.ceil(len(self.df) / float(self.batch_size))).astype(np.int)


    def __getitem__(self, idx) :
        batch_x = self.df.iloc[idx * self.batch_size : (idx+1) * self.batch_size]
        labels = pd.to_numeric(batch_x["label"]).to_numpy()
        # Here are the textual features
        textual_f = None
        # Here are the numeric features
        numeric_f = None
        # Here are the OHE features
        ohe_f = None
        # Here is an image
        im_f = None
        
        
        if self.df.textual_features:  
            textual_f = {}
            for feature in self.df.textual_features:
                textual_f[feature] = batch_x[feature]
                
        if self.df.numeric_features:  
            numeric_f = {}
            for feature in self.df.numeric_features:
                numeric_f[feature] = batch_x[feature]

        
        if self.df.ohe_features:
            ohe_f = {}
            # print(self.df.L_OHE[0].tolist())
            for feature in self.df.L_OHE[0].tolist():
                ohe_f[feature] = batch_x[feature]
        
        try:
            # Get all images from the batch
            img_locations = names_file[names_file['path'].isin(batch_x['image'])].index
            # print(img_locations)
            im_f = matrix_images[img_locations,:,:,:]
        except Exception as e:
            print("error",e)
            pass
        inputs = [textual_f,numeric_f,ohe_f,im_f]
        return inputs,labels
```

I then define generator for both training and test sets.

```
# df is a personnalized class and herits from dataset
# This part just split indexes into one part for training and one for testing
df.df_train_test_split_index()

# Subset for training data
train_data = df.iloc[df.index_train]
train_data = DataSet(
    numeric_features=numeric_features,
    textual_features=textual_features,
    ohe_features=ohe_features,
    data=train_data,
    columns=train_data.columns,
)

# Subset for test data
test_data = df.iloc[df.index_test]
test_data = DataSet(
    numeric_features=numeric_features,
    textual_features=textual_features,
    ohe_features=ohe_features,
    data=test_data,
    columns=test_data.columns,
    
)
# Define list of OHE features for the custom Dataset
train_data.L_OHE = df.L_OHE
test_data.L_OHE = df.L_OHE

batch_size=256

# Define generators
traingen = My_Custom_Generator(batch_size=batch_size,df = train_data)
testgen = My_Custom_Generator(batch_size=batch_size,df = test_data)

# Training 
epochs = 10
history = Dense_embedding_model.fit(
    traingen,  #
    validation_data=testgen,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
)
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2673/1793433158.py in <module>
     36 
     37 epochs = 10
---> 38 history = Dense_embedding_model.fit(
     39     traingen,  #
     40     validation_data=testgen,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     56   try:
     57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (256,) where an element of shape (None, None) was expected.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 275, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 649, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1035, in generator_py_func
    raise TypeError(

TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (256,) where an element of shape (None, None) was expected.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_12]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (256,) where an element of shape (None, None) was expected.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 275, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 649, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1035, in generator_py_func
    raise TypeError(

TypeError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (256,) where an element of shape (None, None) was expected.


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_2319]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

This is the summary of the custom model Dense_embedding_model

```
Model: "Deep_embedded_model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_image (InputLayer)       [(None, 4, 4, 64)]   0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_District (InputLayer)    [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_Sub_District (InputLayer  [(None, 1)]         0           []                               
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 input_Crop (InputLayer)        [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_Block (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_State (InputLayer)       [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_Cluster (InputLayer)     [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_image (Flatten)        (None, 1024)         0           ['input_image[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 Embedding_District (Embedding)  (None, 1, 20)       6180        ['input_District[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 Embedding_Sub_District (Embedd  (None, 1, 20)       12000       ['input_Sub_District[0][0]']     
 ing)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 Embedding_Crop (Embedding)     (None, 1, 20)        900         ['input_Crop[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 Embedding_Block (Embedding)    (None, 1, 20)        11140       ['input_Block[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 Embedding_State (Embedding)    (None, 1, 20)        260         ['input_State[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 Embedding_Cluster (Embedding)  (None, 1, 20)        240         ['input_Cluster[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 Dense_layer_img0 (Dense)       (None, 512)          524800      ['Flatten_image[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_District (Flatten)     (None, 20)           0           ['Embedding_District[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_Sub_District (Flatten)  (None, 20)          0           ['Embedding_Sub_District[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_Crop (Flatten)         (None, 20)           0           ['Embedding_Crop[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_Block (Flatten)        (None, 20)           0           ['Embedding_Block[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_State (Flatten)        (None, 20)           0           ['Embedding_State[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 Flatten_Cluster (Flatten)      (None, 20)           0           ['Embedding_Cluster[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 input_Area_Sown_Ha (InputLayer  [(None, 1)]         0           []                               
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 input_Area_Insured_Ha (InputLa  [(None, 1)]         0           []                               
 yer)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 input_SI_Per_Ha_Inr_Ha (InputL  [(None, 1)]         0           []                               
 ayer)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 input_Sum_Insured_Inr (InputLa  [(None, 1)]         0           []                               
 yer)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 input_Indemnity_Level (InputLa  [(None, 1)]         0           []                               
 yer)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2005 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2006 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2007 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2008 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2009 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2010 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2011 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2012 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2013 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2014 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2015 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_year_2016 (InputLayer)   [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 Dense_layer_img1 (Dense)       (None, 256)          131328      ['Dense_layer_img0[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatted (Concatenate)        (None, 137)          0           ['Flatten_District[0][0]',       
                                                                  'Flatten_Sub_District[0][0]',   
                                                                  'Flatten_Crop[0][0]',           
                                                                  'Flatten_Block[0][0]',          
                                                                  'Flatten_State[0][0]',          
                                                                  'Flatten_Cluster[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_Area_Sown_Ha[0][0]',     
                                                                  'input_Area_Insured_Ha[0][0]',  
                                                                  'input_SI_Per_Ha_Inr_Ha[0][0]', 
                                                                  'input_Sum_Insured_Inr[0][0]',  
                                                                  'input_Indemnity_Level[0][0]',  
                                                                  'input_year_2005[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2006[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2007[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2008[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2009[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2010[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2011[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2012[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2013[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2014[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2015[0][0]',        
                                                                  'input_year_2016[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 Dense_layer_img2 (Dense)       (None, 128)          32896       ['Dense_layer_img1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 concatted2 (Concatenate)       (None, 265)          0           ['concatted[0][0]',              
                                                                  'Dense_layer_img2[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 Dense0 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          26600       ['concatted2[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 Dropout0 (Dropout)             (None, 100)          0           ['Dense0[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 Dense1 (Dense)                 (None, 50)           5050        ['Dropout0[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 Dropout1 (Dropout)             (None, 50)           0           ['Dense1[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 output (Dense)                 (None, 1)            51          ['Dropout1[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 751,445
Trainable params: 751,445
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Here is the output for a batchsize of 1 of the generator to help vizualize what the output of the generator is

```
([{'District': 8665    285
Name: District, dtype: int64, 'Sub_District': 8665    569
Name: Sub_District, dtype: int64, 'Crop': 8665    16
Name: Crop, dtype: int64, 'Block': 8665    132
Name: Block, dtype: int64, 'State': 8665    9
Name: State, dtype: int64, 'Cluster': 8665    6
Name: Cluster, dtype: int64}, {'Area_Sown_Ha': 8665   -0.275499
Name: Area_Sown_Ha, dtype: float32, 'Area_Insured_Ha': 8665   -0.096487
Name: Area_Insured_Ha, dtype: float32, 'SI_Per_Ha_Inr_Ha': 8665   -1.444171
Name: SI_Per_Ha_Inr_Ha, dtype: float32, 'Sum_Insured_Inr': 8665   -0.202066
Name: Sum_Insured_Inr, dtype: float32, 'Indemnity_Level': 8665   -0.049408
Name: Indemnity_Level, dtype: float32}, {'year_2005': 8665    0
Name: year_2005, dtype: uint8, 'year_2006': 8665    0
Name: year_2006, dtype: uint8, 'year_2007': 8665    0
Name: year_2007, dtype: uint8, 'year_2008': 8665    0
Name: year_2008, dtype: uint8, 'year_2009': 8665    0
Name: year_2009, dtype: uint8, 'year_2010': 8665    0
Name: year_2010, dtype: uint8, 'year_2011': 8665    0
Name: year_2011, dtype: uint8, 'year_2012': 8665    0
Name: year_2012, dtype: uint8, 'year_2013': 8665    0
Name: year_2013, dtype: uint8, 'year_2014': 8665    1
Name: year_2014, dtype: uint8, 'year_2015': 8665    0
Name: year_2015, dtype: uint8, 'year_2016': 8665    0
Name: year_2016, dtype: uint8}, array([[[[0.        , 0.576553  , 0.        , ..., 0.02997562,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.894354  , 0.        , ..., 0.17362705,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 1.4560161 , 0.        , ..., 0.5400844 ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.55522037, 0.        , ..., 0.55954516,
          0.        , 0.35267243]],

        [[0.        , 0.25733173, 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.41282725, 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.63072217, 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.42319518, 0.        , ..., 0.63062006,
          0.        , 0.6690183 ]],

        [[0.        , 1.0148075 , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.65953946, 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.5407673 , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.6012098 , 0.        , ..., 0.3009832 ,
          0.        , 0.7469875 ]],

        [[0.        , 0.8481745 , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.6432533 , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.31285512, 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.7883035 , 0.        , ..., 0.09375674,
          0.0399389 , 0.        ]]]], dtype=float32)], array([1310]))
```